# Do I have to do what my senior project advisor tells me to do?

Tags: advisor, writing, undergraduate

I'm an undergraduate writing my senior project paper. Had a good advisor who approved my topic and just let me write, we talked once every other week and he'd just share useful articles, give feedback on what I'd written, etc.

I had to change advisor due to schedule conflicts and my current advisor is a professor I don't really have a good relationship with. I feel like she's holding me back, because instead of just letting me write (I did all my research last semester and this semester. I just want to write, I got 25+ pages to do) She's very overbearing, giving me lots of small little assignments and picking them apart with constant criticism. Not to sound arrogant, but I'm perfectly fine just writing the paper on my own, I'd prefer minimal intervention.

My question is: as long as I finish the paper on time and it's well written, do I have to jump through every hoop? What is the best thing to do for me in this situation? I'm looking to be as autonomous as possible and just get the paper done with minimum intervention.

Comment: Presumably, you would like to get a good grade. You might want to ponder who will grade your paper.

Comment: Is there any chance you might *learn* something from her that way? Letting people do whatever they want can be nice, but it also means that you might not learn a lot of things which you should learn during a project. Plus, it is much more work to give constant feedback, and people hate you for it. So try to see if she is actually trying to teach you something, rather than giving you a superficial nice feeling.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes. Jump through every hoop.

Long answer: Yes. Jump through every hoop. What you see as tedious, time-consuming work could actually be setting you up to be an even better researcher/writer. And, frankly, you're not as good as you think you are. No one is. Everyone can stand to have their work picked apart, reviewed, edited, chewed up and spit back out again. You've got 25+ papers to write, according to your post, so get to writing them.

I've been through undergrad and Masters and have a whole lifetime of experience long after those years have passed by. In life, you're going to be pushed, tested, cut down and built back up again. This is one of those times. You may not like it now, but when you come out on the other side, you will appreciate whatever it is you learn from having someone push you like this advisor is. And, if you don't see what you gained from it as the years go on, take a step back and re-evaluate yourself and where you end up and be objective about how she made you better than you thought you were. That's what good teachers do.

Comment: 25+ *pages*, not *papers*.

Answer (score 0):

She must have other advisees also (current or previous).

Find some previous advisees and discuss with them how to handle her specially how to get good grades from her.

Meet some current advisees and check how they are getting along.

I hope you will find some clue to get good grades while keeping an easy relation.